# linux RSS from ps RES from TOP

Tags: linux, memory, command, redhat, ps

Linux : RedHat/Fedora

What is the difference between these memory values:

- RES from top command
- RSS from ps command

Answer (score 12):

If you are talking about the difference between the `RES` column in `top -p $(pidof process)` and the `RSS` column in the `ps aux | grep $(pidof process)` command, **there is no difference**, as both the tools get this value from the `/proc/$(pidof process)/stat` file.

You can always cat `/proc/$(pidof process)/status` for a human readable format.